# xcolor package will not map text to color

Tags: color, r

I downloaded the xcolor package from the CTAN website, which includes xcolor.sty, svgnam.def, and xcolor.pro. The table that I output contains the name of the color in text, without the actual color. This is only a problem for the colors in the %Color definition% section- aka MidnightBlue from svgnam does not give me any problems, but in my table, where a cell should be colored LightBlue, I instead have the text LightBlue in the cell. Any ideas how to get around this?

```
\documentclass[hidelinks, svngames]{report}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
        linkcolor = MidnightBlue,
        urlcolor  = MidnightBlue,
        citecolor = MidnightBlue,
        anchorcolor = MidnightBlue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[autoplay=false, loop=false, poster=last]{animate}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\hypersetup{
 colorlinks   = true,
 citecolor    = gray,
 linkcolor = MidnightBlue
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Colour definition%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{Blue}{RGB}{53,103,240}
\definecolor{LightBlue}{RGB}{216,223,242}
```

EDIT: Run this for a minimum verifiable example. I think the error lies in the two backslashes in "\cellcolor" but I get another error if I remove a backslash.

```
temp<-read.table(text=paste("Action      Weight
                          1  Addition     1
                          2  Deletion     2
                          3  UpWeight     3 
                          4  DownWeight   4",sep=""),header=TRUE)

for(i in 1:nrow(temp)){
    if(nrow(temp)>0){
      temp[,1:ncol(temp)]<-"\\cellcolor{LightBlue}\\textcolor{white}{  }"
      temp[,2]<-paste0("\\cellcolor{LightBlue}\\textcolor{black}{",as.character(temp$Action[i]),"}")
      temp$Action<-NULL
    }
  }
```

Comment: please fix your example so that it is an example of the problem,  so we can run it and see the problem and debug.

Comment: you should not have had to get xcolor from CTAN, it should be part of any tex distribution.

Comment: Once again you have posted R code without mentioning it is R or even tagging the question.  It is _easy_ for you to tell if you have posted a verifiable example,  just do what you are asking others to do and copy the above into a new directory, is it then possible to reproduce the error.

Comment: If you get an error show the error from the log file, all the lines from `!` to `?` in a code block so line endings are preserved.

Comment: There is a problem with your R code.  See [Why doe backslash behave strangely inside strings](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-does-backslash-behave-strangely-inside-strings_003f).

Comment: One other comment: there are good R packages for outputting tabular material to LaTeX, so it seems odd that you would need to build your table by hand like you are doing.

Comment: You have `\usepackage{color}` twice and `xcolor` once. You only need the `xcolor`. There's no need to pass `hidelinks` and `svngames` (sic) to `\documentclass`, just give `hidelinks` to `hyperref` and you've already got (the correctly spelled) `svgnames` being passed to `xcolor`. The `table` option to `xcolor` loads `colortbl` so there's no need for that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For closure, I reinstalled the xcolor package and deleted the excess \usepackage lines (as pointed out in @TH's comment). The combination of the two seemed to work! Thanks to the community for continuing to push the principles of how to ask a good question